# Problem baking Normal Maps from high to low poly - grey result

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, texture-baking

I selected the High poly mesh first then the low poly. (both have the same coordinates) Created a new image in the uv map called normal map v2. I created a material with an image texture node and selected it, then selected "normal" for the bake type and hit bake. I keep getting a grey normal map and I dont know what I'm doing wrong.
[image]

Comment: bump bump bump bump

Comment: Check High poly object for materials\textures, disable them.